# Javascript-Generated SVG Not Updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a script that adds elements to an inline SVG image via jQuery, but the new elements don't seem to be showing up. The output is perfectly valid; I can copy it into the original file, reload it, and it will render just fine. But when the script generates it, the new elements aren't visible.

Here is a snippet that replicates the problem: http://tinkerbin.com/7OmDWlsz

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not see any svg output if the elements are not in the svg namespace.

Try replacing your script snippet with this:

```
var slices = 10;

for(i = 0; i < 360; i += 360 / slices) {
  var element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polyline");
  element.setAttribute("points", "0,0 -10,100 10,100");
  element.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(" + i + ")");
  $('#rotate').append(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to much @Erik Dahlström, I may add a contribution to this. Here is the function I define in order to build svg trees :

```
Node.prototype.svg_grow = function(node_name, node_attr) {
    n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", node_name);
    this.appendChild(n);
    if (typeof node_attr !== 'undefined') {
        for (key in node_attr) {
            n.setAttribute(key, node_attr[key]);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

So you can just use `svg_grow()` on any node like this :

```
s_g = document.getElementById("parent");
s_rect = s_g.svg_grow('rect', {x:0, y:0, width:480, height:640});
```

which just do :

```
<g id="parent">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="480" height="640" />
</g>
```